# Plot the minimum of a function of two variables , where the minimum is taken with respect to just one variable

Tags: plotting, numerics, mathematical-optimization

Suppose I have a function $f(x,y)$ of two variables $x$ and $y$. Suppose that: for each fixed $y$, the function $f(x,y)$ is non-zero, odd and periodic in $x$, with one maximum and one minimum in the period $x \in [0, h(y)]$. So here the period $h(y)$ depends on $y$.

Now I define the function $g(y) = \min_{x} f(x,y)$ ,  i.e. $g$ is defined as the minimum of $f(x,y)$ in $x$ for each $y$.

How can I plot $g(y)$?

Comment: A concrete example of `f[x,y]` would be helpful.

Comment: is this the problem you're facing `Plot[g[y],{y,0,h[y]}]` namely the `h[y]` in the range for y?

Comment: My function is  complicated (it involves elliptic functions depending on $x$ and $y$ in a nontrivial way) so perhaps better to avoid it as an example here @ChrisK

Comment: I was thinking to use Plot[NMinValue[f[x,y],x], {y, "range"}] - but for some reason, it gives me the statement "Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded. " I think it's because $f(x,y)$ goes to infinity at certain points, for every fixed $y$; however, that shouldn't be a problem as I am evaluating it am minima of $y$... @user42582

Comment: You are much more likely to get help if you provide an example.

Comment: @Alex correct me if I'm wrong but your problem, then, is *not* with `Plot` but with `NMinValue` possibly; also, it would be a good idea-like others have suggested already-if you could provide a *minimally functional instance* of your problem in order for more knowledgeable users to provide concrete guidance; this is too hand-wavy, if I may say so